# NSArray element to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have application where I receive from socket message like: **"\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n"**. I convert this message into UTF8 string with code:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then I try to separate command and time from this string:

```
NSArray *nums = [command componentsSeparatedByString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", (char)13]];
NSLog(@"First separate = %@", nums);
if ([nums count] == 3)
{
    NSArray *nums1 = [[nums objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    NSLog(@"second separate = %@", nums1);
    if ([nums1 count] == 2)
    {
        NSString* strState = [(NSString *)[nums1 objectAtIndex:0] description];
        NSLog(@"State = %@", strState);

        ...
    }
}
```

in the log I see next:

```
    First separate = (
    "IDLE|03/17/2013 19:48",
    "\n"
second separate = (
    "IDLE",
    "03/17/2013 19:48"
State = I
```

After second separating in the 0 elements I have text **IDLE**, but when I try to get this text I  **strState** variable, I see only first character of this text.
Can anybody help me get full command of this element?

Thank you.

**UPDATE1**
As I say previously I get from socket message like:**"\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n"**
I'm sure that the server send me this message.
in the Socket read callback I'm use next code for reading this message:

```
int result = CFReadStreamRead(_inputStream, (UInt8*)[data mutableBytes], length);
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Here app read 50 bytes and this is right for this message? you can see my debugger at this point in the next picture:
[image: Debugger in the socket]

but in the **newStr** member I see only *\r*.
then I send try separate this message with code I wrote above.
When I try separate message logger show me all message instead of *\r*:
[image: array after separate]
Thank you

Comment: Change: `NSString* strState = [(NSString *)[nums1 objectAtIndex:0] description];` to `NSString* strState = nums1[0];`. Any better?

Comment: I have tried with @"\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n" . However [nums1 count] returns 2.. do u have any other sample strings to test ?

Comment: Also, you can get `nums` by doing: `NSArray *nums = [command componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];`. `\r` is the character literal for carriage return.

Comment: @rmaddy 
I tried change my code to NSString* strState = nums1[0]; bbu nothing changed :(((

Comment: @Ramshad
"\r\nSTREAMANDCAPTURE|03/17/2013 19:48\n" -- this a second message from socket? but result is same as in the previously :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using sscanf()?

```
  char command[COMMAND_SIZE_LIMIT];   
  char date[DATE_SIZE_LIMIT];
  char time[TIME_SIZE_LIMIT];

  sscanf (input, "\r\n%[^|]%*[|]%s%s\n", command, date, time);
```

(Note: Above is example code; you've got a security issue if the scanned string has oversized command or datetime substrings.)

```
# test
ebg@ebg$ ./foo
Input: '
IDLE|03/17/2013 19:48
'
Command: 'IDLE'
Date: '03/17/2013'
Time: '19:48'
```

It is easy to convert NSString <==> C string.

Comment: I'm add this code to my app 
`const char* input = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"state"] UTF8String];
    char command1[20];
    char date[20];
    char time[20];
    
    sscanf (input, "\r\n%[^|]%*[|]%s%s\n", command1, date, time);`
bit in the  **input** I see only "\r" and do not see any another text

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly straightforward way to accomplish what you want using the `-[NSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]` method. Passing the whitespace and newline character set allows you to trim the leading and trailing whitespace and newlines from your string, and then you only need to do a single call to `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

```
NSString *raw = @"\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n";
NSString *trimmedString = [raw stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSArray *components = [trimmedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
NSString *command = components[0];
NSString *time = components[1];
NSLog(@"command = %@, time = %@",command,time);
```

This code yields the following output:

```
command = IDLE, time = 03/17/2013 19:48
```

Comment: A add your code in to my project and after `NSString *time = components[1];` I do not see a goo result here link to screenshot of my debugger  http://s45.radikal.ru/i107/1303/d5/7c927d1e1b06.png

Comment: @kroumvud I don't know what's going on with your debugger, I've never seen that before. I've updated my code to show the exact test code I wrote as a complete example, for your reference. Also, what happens when you stop in the debugger and type `po command` and `po time`?

Comment: When I'm add your code with static `NSString *raw = @"\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n";`--everything works fine, but firs I get this string I get from the socket like NSData:
`result = CFReadStreamRead(_inputStream, (UInt8*)[data mutableBytes], length);NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
and only then I try to get command and time from this string
When stop in the debugger in the socket read method I see next:
http://s52.radikal.ru/i138/1303/5a/75707639c85d.png
Where I see that app read 50 symbols... but in the newStr only "\r"

Comment: @kroumvud Your question states the input is "\r\nIDLE|03/17/2013 19:48\n". If that's not the actual input then please update your question with what you're actually getting.